# Retrieving cookies from google using PHP/CURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl, authentication, gmail

I'm trying to create a script that allows users to login once (using same username & password on the domain) so that they can access the portal and gmail, instead of signing in twice (one to the portal & the other to their gmail).

I have been trying to retrieve cookies from the gmail but having no luck. Has anyone attempted this before with success?

Please let me know, thanks

Comment: It would be a huge security problem if it would be possible to get the cookis of other pages. Use OAuth mechanism for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/).

Ah [PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) is available.